# recursive update a "Behaviour" in Sodium yields 'thread blocked ...'

Tags: haskell, frp, sodiumfrp

i would update a Behaviour (Cell / Val) from it's current value.

but the following code throws a **thread blocked indefinitely in an MVar operation** exception.

i have expected it prints three times 'value of i: '. 
what did i missing? - thanks.

```
  {-# LANGUAGE RecursiveDo #-}
  module Main where

  import           FRP.Sodium

  main :: IO ()
  main = do
    (e, t) <- sync newEvent

    rec
      b <- sync $ hold 0 $ snapshot (\_ i -> i + 1) e b

    sync $ listen (value b) (\i -> putStrLn $ "value of i: " ++ show i)

    sync $ t "ping"
    sync $ t "ping"
    sync $ t "ping"

    return ()
```

---

- GHCi, version 7.8.3
- sodium-0.11.0.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your recursive let from `RecursiveDo` is in the `IO` monad. The `Reactive` monad also has a `MonadFix` instance. You can define `b` completely within `Reactive` and then use a [`sync`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sodium-0.11.0.3/docs/FRP-Sodium.html#v:sync) around this to execute the entire definition as a transaction.

```
main = do
    (e, t) <- sync newEvent

    b <- sync $
        do
            rec
                b <- hold 0 $ snapshot (\_ i -> i + 1) e b
            return b

    sync $ listen (value b) (\i -> putStrLn $ "value of i: " ++ show i)

    ...
```

The `RecursiveDo` notation isn't helping with an example this simple. The same thing can be written more easily in terms of [`mfix`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Fix.html#v:mfix).

```
main = do
    (e, t) <- sync newEvent

    b <- sync . mfix $ hold 0 . snapshot (\_ i -> i + 1) e

    sync $ listen (value b) (\i -> putStrLn $ "value of i: " ++ show i)

    ...
```

---

It's probably worth mentioning that creating a `Behavior` from an `Event` is usually done with [`accum`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sodium-0.11.0.3/docs/FRP-Sodium.html#v:accum).

```
b <- sync $ accum 0 (const (+1) <$> e)
```

In sodium this is a derived function and is internally defined in terms of `hold`, `snapshot`, and `mfix`.

```
accum :: Context r => a -> Event r (a -> a) -> Reactive r (Behavior r a)
accum z efa = do
    rec
        s <- hold z $ snapshot ($) efa s
    return s
```